# What were other possible solutions proposed to solve the problem of clean weapons separation for the F-18 Super Hornet?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, military, wing, fighter

[image: Canted pylons]

I'm curious as to what other solutions were considered besides canting the pylons.

Comment: How was it handled by other clean-slate designs subsequent to the F-18?

Comment: At least in the helicopter world weapons are canted to minimise drag at cruising speed. There's a quite wide range of speeds and attitudes where weapons can be safely jettisoned. It should be the same for airplane too.

Comment: welcome to aviation.se. I'm sorry, but as currently is phrased, this question is fundamentally asking for opinions. if you can reformulate it such that it can be answered in a factual manner, I'll be more than happy to reopen.

Comment: "I know that..." - Documentation on this please? On all the pics I see, the wing pylons are vertical.